# Format 2 digit value before decimal and 2 digit after decmal, Excel Interop

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I want to read in values out of a cell in an Excel Spreadsheet that could be

10.50

20.25

41.10

I am using the Excel Interop to retrieve the values.

The following works for values less than 10, but when 10 or greater the value gets set to 0. How can I format this correctly using the NumberFormat action?

```
double doubleHours = 0.0;

if (Extension.IsNumeric(excelWorksheet.Cells[rowCount, columnCount].Text))
{
    Excel.Range range = excelWorksheet.Cells[rowCount, columnCount];
    range.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00";

    double.TryParse(excelWorksheet.Cells[rowCount, columnCount].Text, out doubleHours);

    //continue processing
}
```

Comment: `.Text` can return something like "`####`" when the value does not fit, so use `.Value.ToString()` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
double doubleHours = 0.0;
Excel.Range range = excelWorksheet.Cells[rowCount, columnCount];
string value = range.Value2.ToString();

if (double.TryParse(value, out doubleHours)) {
    //continue processing
}
```